# A single word or more professional form of 'swallowing one's pride'

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

A single word is preferred, though a phrase echoing professionalism is fine too.

Edit: here is the context:
'Another video is linked, though instead of having the key line exposing Clinton’s lies and capricious character, denying her support NAFTA and calling the TPP ‘ the gold standard’ were both outright lies, yet neither the moderator nor the journalist decided to write about it. Zurcher **swallows his pride** and concedes the full point to Mr. Trump, ruefully and painfully.'

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence or two showing how you'd like to use this word? You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the term ***acquiescing*** is a *professional* enough replacement of '*swallowing one's pride*'.

> Zurcher ***acquiesces*** and concedes the full point to Mr. Trump,
>   ruefully and painfully.

ODO:

> **[acquiesce](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acquiesce)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [NO OBJECT] Accept something reluctantly but without protest.
>
> ‘Curious but respectful, Cathena acquiesces to the request.’
>   ‘Are
>   they silently acquiescing to the policies of a government that is as
>   mean as Scrooge?’

Answer (score 0):

[self-effacement](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-effacement): the act or fact of keeping oneself in the background, as in humility.

> This will require patience and self-effacement from a man accustomed to dominating the economic-policy discussion.

A thesaurus has many more choices: [self-effacement](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/self-effacement?s=t)

Answer (score -1):

As a devoted son, Fred felt **honor-bound** to speak out publicly in support of his father who had been pilloried by the nation's merciless tabloid press in the wake of the bank's financial collapse.

**Honor-bound:** bound by one's sense of honor or what is morally right; a showing of unusually merited respect. (M-W).

Comment: Someone who undertakes a distasteful task or other activity despite the shame of doing so may be motivated by a sense of honor, but any number of other motivations are possible. An obvious one is money.

Comment: @DanBron Would you be so kind as to elucidate how money might motivate someone to feel honor-bound to do something. My poor addled brain can think only of venal behavior on the part of a person who, in this context, feels "honor-bound"[sic] to do something as quid pro quo for the receipt of a money-payment, etc. If that is the case then what is a positive motivational force becomes a negative one and undermines any sense of honor.

Comment: OP describes someone who "swallows his pride"; nowhere does he use the term "honor bound" or anything approaching it. That idea, and term, was introduced by you, and my original comment was intended to express why I think "honor bound" is inapt or at least insufficient as a synonym for "swallowing one's pride" (which is what OP is asking for). I agree with you that venal motivations for honor-bound activities doesn't make sense, but that's irrelevant, because no one here is talking about honor-bound activities (except you). Money is absolutely a motivation to swallow one's pride.